# My VNC session connects but no display appears

Tags: vnc, tightvnc

I'm trying to get a desktop connection from one Linux host to another. I run this command from my client host:

```
$ vncviewer 10.0.0.4:6001
```

I see the connection with this from my server host:

```
$ sudo netstat -anpt | grep vnc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12928/Xtightvnc    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12928/Xtightvnc    
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:6001           10.0.0.5:34024          ESTABLISHED 12928/Xtightvnc
```

Then after about 30 seconds or so I see this on my client host.

```
vncviewer: VNC server closed connection
```

I expected instead a window to pop up on my client host which looks like a login window on my server host.

Comment: You do not have a connection from what I can see. 127.0.0.1 is the local loopback address. Figure out the connection settings first and do VNC second.

Comment: Thank you @John. The 3rd line in the netstat listing, the one saying ESTABLISHED, is what makes me think I have a connection.